# How to troubleshoot performance issues in Unity 3D

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

We have created a game in Unity and are currently testing on various devices.

Some devices as you'd expect perform better than others, but we are surprised by our testing on iPad 3 and iPhone 4, which we'd have thought would cope better. (simple movements of objects appear quite jittery)

With regards to troubleshooting we have placed a frame rate readout on the screen and we can see that this is very erratic (a target of 60fps can flick anywhere between 24 and 60 seemingly randomly), but I was wondering what other performance diagnostics can be done. Are there plugins that can give readouts/log performance as the game plays that could point to specific events or graphics that cause it all to struggle?

Any other ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So why Android tag? If you are having issues with iPad 3 and iPhone 4, or you are facing issues also in Android device?

Comment: Have you tried the profiler?

Comment: @golergka what is this exactly and how can it help? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Skizo Yes, all kinds of devices but I highlighted the iPad/Iphone4 as these are the higher end devices that aren't performing well

Answer (score 0):

**Profile**

Unity has some excellent tools to enable you to profile your code while it is running, both in the editor and on devices.

This generally involves:

1. Connecting your device to the same wifi network as your development machine, or plugging it in via USB cable
2. Selecting "Dev Build" and "Autoconnect Profiler" when you build your project
3. Opening the profiling window in Unity.

I would suggest that before you try profiling your application on your tablets, you try profiling it in the editor. This will give you an idea of how to best use the profiler, and you may realise what parts of code you can optimise before even running it on your device.

Profiler: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html

**Read up on optimisation** 
Not so much an answer to your question, but read up on various performance gotchas. You don't want to prematurely optimise, but there are certain practices you need to be aware of when developing for mobile devices, keeping your shaders simple, reducing draw-calls, dynamic batching etc.

Various notes on optimisations:

- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/37293/general-ways-to-optimize-frame-rate.html
- http://www.paladinstudios.com/2012/07/30/4-ways-to-increase-performance-of-your-unity-game/